# Change Embed Button Color when using Semantic-UI React

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I am using the Semantic UI React Embed component https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/embed/ and want to change the color of the play button from white to some other color. Any suggestions?

One option is to make the embed `active` which shows the Youtube/ Vimeo button (which offers a good contrast between the background and foreground), but still want to figure this out to maintain uniformity on my webpage since I have not made the rest of my video embeds `active`

[image]

I am slightly new to this library and React, and am finding it hard to understand all the props they offer.

Answer (score 0):

you can override the color by CSS with class

```
.ui.embed>.icon:before {
   color: #ff0000;
 }
```

if you want to set the color by javascript you can make a CSS variable and change that variable value with javascript

```
:root {
   --embed-icon-color: #fff;
}

.ui.embed>.icon:before {
   color: var(--embed-icon-color);
 }
```

And finally in Javascript you can do:

```
 document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--embed-icon-color','#ff0000');
```

Comment: Sorry if this is very obvious. Is there any other option without using css class? I am trying to keep the css inline in the React file like so: <Grid.Column width={6} style={{ marginTop: "1.5em" }}>